# Linearization of cones

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis, cones

Suppose that $K$ is a closed convex cone in $R^{n}$. Is there a "nice" function $f:R^{n} \rightarrow R^{m}$ so that $f(K)$ is a subspace? What about an approximate subspace?

Comment: Can you clarify, perhaps by example, what you have in mind? Of course there is a linear map to $R^1$ such that $f(K)$ is either 0 or the entire line.

Comment: @SergeiIvanov I am afraid I have no example - that's why I am asking for existence. My motivation for this is to try to obtain results on cones from results on subspaces via this embedding.

Comment: We should possibly clarify whether (i) we are interested in a `philosophical' assignment of closed convex cones $K$ to linear subspaces or (ii) a fixed function $f$ such that the images $f(K)$ are always linear subspaces. In case (ii) I wonder whether or not the assumption that $f$ be continuous and maps linear subspaces (themselves closed convex cones) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to linear subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^m$   necessarily forces $f$ to be, say, linear.

Comment: @J.Martel Farkas's lemma seems to me to be a sort of philosophical assignment; I am more interested in what you called case (ii) - any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify your sense of `cone'. If $K$ is a cone in the sense that $x\in K$ implies $\mathbb{R} x \subset K$, then it appears that a closed convex cone is necessarily a linear subspace.

Comment: A set $K$ is a convex cone if $\lambda x+\mu y \in K$ for $x,y \in K$ and $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: On a symmetric cone there is a logarithm function, defined on the interior of the cone which maps the cone to a subspace.  For example, on the cone of real positive definite matrices, the range of the logarithm is all symmetric matrices.

Comment: @BrianLins Can you give me a reference where it's spelt out in some detail? Thanks a mil!

Comment: @Brian: what do you mean by `symmetric'? Because $0$-symmetric (i.e. $x\in K$ whenever $=x\in K$) means: every $0$-symmetric convex cone is already a linear subspace. What exactly is this `log' function?